# installing pyaudio on mac

Tags: python, macos, pyaudio

I am trying to install pyaudio on my system.

System Specification: `macOS Mojava`

Version: `10.14.2 (18C54)`

Error that I am getting is this:

```
    Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ab/42/b4f04721c5c5bfc196ce156b3c768998ef8c0ae3654ed29ea5020c749a6b/PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pyaudio ... error
  Complete output from command /Users/dsnanaware/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/r7/64j7w40s1fn8bmdkblq1pbym0000gn/T/pip-install-yro3wf2m/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/r7/64j7w40s1fn8bmdkblq1pbym0000gn/T/pip-wheel-3d4sruhv --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
  copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
  running build_ext
  building '_portaudio' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/dsnanaware/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/dsnanaware/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DMACOSX=1 -I/Users/dsnanaware/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/_portaudiomodule.o
  src/_portaudiomodule.c:27:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
   #include <stdio.h>
                     ^
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pyaudio
  Running setup.py clean for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
  Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    Complete output from command /Users/dsnanaware/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/r7/64j7w40s1fn8bmdkblq1pbym0000gn/T/pip-install-yro3wf2m/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/r7/64j7w40s1fn8bmdkblq1pbym0000gn/T/pip-record-4xqsbegf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/dsnanaware/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/dsnanaware/anaconda3/include -arch x86_64 -DMACOSX=1 -I/Users/dsnanaware/anaconda3/include/python3.6m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-3.6/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:27:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
     #include <stdio.h>
                       ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Users/dsnanaware/anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/r7/64j7w40s1fn8bmdkblq1pbym0000gn/T/pip-install-yro3wf2m/pyaudio/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/r7/64j7w40s1fn8bmdkblq1pbym0000gn/T/pip-record-4xqsbegf/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/r7/64j7w40s1fn8bmdkblq1pbym0000gn/T/pip-install-yro3wf2m/pyaudio/
```

Method that I have tried to fix this:

1. `brew install portaudio`
2. `pip install pyaudio`

But even after trying this I am getting the same error.

Can anyone help me with this error??

Thank You !!

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

```
brew update
brew install portaudio
brew link --overwrite portaudio
pip install pyaudio
```

https://medium.com/@moon_is_beautiful/when-cant-install-pyaudio-with-pip-190973840dbf

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked following this Gist

https://gist.github.com/jiaaro/9767512210a1d80a8a0d

Install portaudio using homebrew (or method of your choice)

```
brew install portaudio
```

create $HOME/.pydistutils.cfg using the include and lib directories of your portaudio install:

```
[build_ext]
include_dirs=/Users/jrobert1271/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.20140130/include/
library_dirs=/Users/jrobert1271/homebrew/Cellar/portaudio/19.20140130/lib/
```

Then in your virtualenv:

```
 pip install --global-option='build_ext' --global-option='-I/usr/local/include' --global-option='-L/usr/local/lib' pyaudio
```